# Spring @Autowired failed with Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

When I was using Hibernate I had a configuration class like this:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class HibernateConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        return new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    }
}
```

Then I want to make sure this configuration class works fine, so I wrote an unit test like below:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = HibernateConfiguration.class)
public class HibernateConfigurationTest {
    @Autowired
    private LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean;

    @Test
    public void someTest(){
    }
}
```

Then Intellij keeps telling me this message, and it also fail the compile so it's not an Intellij bug:

> Could not autowire. No beans of `LocalSessionFactoryBean` type found.

And after I changed the `LocalSessionFactoryBean` to `SessionFactory` it works fine.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = HibernateConfiguration.class)
public class HibernateConfigurationTest {
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory localSessionFactoryBean;

    @Test
    public void someTest(){
    }
}
```

And below is the source code of `LocalSessionFactoryBean`:

```
public class LocalSessionFactoryBean extends HibernateExceptionTranslator
    implements FactoryBean<SessionFactory>, ResourceLoaderAware, InitializingBean, DisposableBean {
}
```

Below are some version information:

```
<properties>
    <springframework.version>4.0.6.RELEASE</springframework.version>
    <hibernate.version>4.3.6.Final</hibernate.version>
    <mysql.version>5.1.31</mysql.version>
    <joda-time.version>2.3</joda-time.version>
    <testng.version>6.9.4</testng.version>
    <mockito.version>1.10.19</mockito.version>
    <h2.version>1.4.187</h2.version>
    <dbunit.version>2.2</dbunit.version>
</properties>
```

**So why Spring could not autowire when I was using `LocalSessionFactoryBean`?** I think I have some misunderstand about the type deduction of Spring bean, because in my opinion the method below `@Bean` in the configuration class will register a bean which type is `LocalSessionFactoryBean`, rather than `SessionFactory`, and then the autowired should works fine but it didn't. Can anyone please give me some learning material about that? I tried to search something like that and got very little useful result. With many thanks!

Comment: Which version of Spring are you using? Not sure if it's relevant yet, but sometimes odd behaviors can be tied to a specific version.

Comment: Might seem odd at first, but did you try to rename your `sessionFactory()` method to `localSessionFactoryBean()`?

Comment: I updated the version info on the post, and just tried to rename it, still not work

Comment: One "pattern" I see is that SessionFactory is an Interface and LocalSessionFactoryBean is a Class and I know Spring handles injection/proxying differently between the two, I don't know if that could be it.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-extension-factorybean

Comment: Why would you autowire `LocalSessionFactoryBean`?? I think you need to read about what Spring is and how you are supposed to use it. The documentation linked above is a good place to start...

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject the SqlSessionFactory instead of the SessionFactory.